# useSelector is not updating the state in reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to update the `state.user.price` state to some other value using `reduxjs/toolkit` but it is not working properly. I know this has to do with immutablity then I tried returning new objects without changing them but it didn't work.

```js
const initialUserState = {
  isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
  carName: "",
  price: "any",
  avaliablity: "any",
  type: "any"
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: initialUserState,
  reducers: {
    handleAuthState: state => {
      state.isLoggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem("token");
    },
    changeCarName: (state, action) => {
      state.carName = action.payload;
    },
    changeAvailablity: (state, action) => {
      state.avaliablity = action.payload;
    },
    changeType: (state, action) => {
      state.type = action.payload;
    },
    changePrice: (state, action) => {
      state.price = action.payload;
    }
  }
});
```

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    UI: UISlice.reducer,
    user: userSlice.reducer,
    car: carSlice.reducer
  }
});

export default store;
export const userActions = userSlice.actions;
```

```
const Filters = () => {
  const type = useSelector(state => state.user.type);
  const price = useSelector(state => state.user.price);
  const carName = useSelector(state => state.user.carName);
  const availablity = useSelector(state => state.user.availablity);

  const sendRequest = async () => {
    console.log("priceInSendRequestFunction = ", price);
  }

  const priceHandler = event => {
    if (event.target.value === "") {
      dispatch(userActions.changePrice("any"))
    } else {
      console.log("event.target.value = ", event.target.value);
      dispatch(userActions.changePrice(event.target.value));
    }
    sendRequest();
  }
  return (
    <Select onChange={priceHandler} placeholder="Select Price">
      <option value="2000">Below 2000</option>
      <option value="4000">2000 - 4000</option>
      <option value="6000">4000 - 6000</option>
      <option value="infinity">Above 6000</option>
      <option value="any">Any</option>
    </Select>
  )
}
```

The value of `price` in `sendRequest` function should get the updated value but it is getting another value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current selected `price` state is closed over in callback scope when `priceHandler` is called. `priceHandler` dispatches an action to the store and immediately calls `sendRequest`. The component has yet to rerender and access any updated Redux state values.

You can forward the value to `sendRequest` that you are updating the state to:

```js
const sendRequest = async (price) => {
  console.log("priceInSendRequestFunction = ", price);
};

const priceHandler = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  const newPrice = value || "any";

  console.log({ newPrice });
  dispatch(userActions.changePrice(newPrice));

  sendRequest(newPrice);
};
```

Or you can import the `store` and access the current state directly:

```js
import store from '../path/to/store';

...

const sendRequest = async () => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const { price } = state.user;

  console.log("priceInSendRequestFunction = ", price);
};

const priceHandler = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  const newPrice = value || "any";

  console.log({ newPrice });
  dispatch(userActions.changePrice(newPrice));

  sendRequest();
};
```

If the `sendRequest` function/logic is effectively a "side-effect" then an alternative might be to convert the `changePrice` action into an asynchronous action, e.g. a Thunk.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialUserState = {
  isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
  carName: "",
  price: "any",
  avaliablity: "any",
  type: "any"
};

export const changePrice = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/changePrice",
  async (price, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log("price in changePrice action = ", price);
    try {
      // side-effect to send price ...somewhere
      ...
      return price;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: initialUserState,
  reducers: {
    handleAuthState: state => {
      state.isLoggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem("token");
    },
    changeCarName: (state, action) => {
      state.carName = action.payload;
    },
    changeAvailablity: (state, action) => {
      state.avaliablity = action.payload;
    },
    changeType: (state, action) => {
      state.type = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      // Update local price state if side-effect successful
      .addCase(changePrice.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.price = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```

```
const Filters = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const {
    availablity,
    carName,
    price,
    type,
  } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  const priceHandler = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const newPrice = value || "any";

    console.log({ newPrice });
    dispatch(userActions.changePrice(newPrice));
  }

  return (
    <Select onChange={priceHandler} placeholder="Select Price">
      <option value="2000">Below 2000</option>
      <option value="4000">2000 - 4000</option>
      <option value="6000">4000 - 6000</option>
      <option value="infinity">Above 6000</option>
      <option value="any">Any</option>
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Comment: For someone who checked they did everything right, that is: either using Redux Toolkit and mutating state or regular Redux and not mutating the state, having the store correctly configured, checking in Redux Dev Tools to see that the data is indeed updated there, and noticing that the component where the `useSelector` hook is used seems to have old data, before the last mutation, this is the answer you're looking for!